# Length of a module, intersection theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, intersection-theory

I have a question to Proposition 7.1 "Intersection Theory", Fulton:

What is the length of $A/J$?

The length $l_R(M)$ is defined for an $R$-module $M$. Over which ring do I view $A/J$?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

$A/J$ can be viewed as a module over $A$ or $A/J$; the length is the same.

Comment: In the book they also talk about the length$(\mathcal{O}_{Z,W})$. Is this the same like $l_{A/J}(A/J)$?

Comment: Yes, I would assume the length of a ring $R$ means its length regarded as an $R$-module.